# No data reported to the log workspace for Azure Container Insight - Openshift Cluster

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-aks, azure-monitoring, aro

I have onboarded an ARO Cluster in the Azure Container insight as shown in the picture below, but no data is being reported (no nodes, no pods..etc).
I have deployed the Oms Agent in openshift using DeamonSet and I can see Heartbeats sent by the agents (Pods) in the Log Analytics workspace.
Could you please help on getting the ARO cluster correctly onboarded in Azure Container Insight?
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft support :
This is because ARO is no longer a supported resource type for Container Insights, as per this notice: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-monitor-containers-insights-support-for-azure-red-hat-openshift-v4x-will-be-retired-by-31-may-2022/

You should Arc enabled your ARO cluster and setup Container Insights following these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-enable-arc-enabled-clusters